# Can I use a GPL data collection agent in commercial software

Tags: commercial, gpl-2, agpl-3.0

I am trying to create a commercial monitoring software using Zabbix agent. Zabbix agent is a data collection software installed in a remote computer that collects the data and sends to a central server via internet.

I will ask customers to install Zabbix agent and then point to my sever where I plan to collect the information and show the data on the website without using any Zabbix component.

From my understanding this is allowed in GPL but not AGPL.

Comment: What is the protocol that your server software will follow to communicate with, authenticate to, and instruct the agent?  How have you acquainted yourself with the details of this protocol?

Comment: Even though I have not studied the protocol yet but, it would definitely be using some kind of http or https protocol. Probably using the REST api or something similar.

Comment: I repeat the question: how do you intend to study it?  Do the Zabbix authors publish the protocol?

Comment: I found some documents on their website. One of them is here: https://www.zabbix.org/wiki/Docs/protocols/zabbix_agent/3.4

Comment: Have you read [Mimicking an AGPLv3-licensed server for reading open data](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/7111/mimicking-an-agplv3-licensed-server-for-reading-open-data-are-there-licence-leg)?  Does that answer your question?

Comment: How are you distributing your software to your customer? From what you describe maybe you are not distributing software at all; you just are offering a service via your server.

Comment: @Brandin yes that is true. I plan to ask the customer to install Zabbix agent (from their website) and then in agent settings, point it to my server (instead of Zabbix server). When the agent sends packet I plan to interpret it and then show users some statistics on my site. Does that explain it?

Comment: @MadHatter The article you mentioned is similar, also it is for more restrictive AGPL. Trying to figure out if that exactly is same as mine.

Comment: @Samuel the AGPL's requirements are a pure superset of the GPL's, so if AGPL permits this, then so will GPL.